# Ссылка на скрытый товар в корзине WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте есть скрытые товары, которые доступны по ссылке. При добавлении их в корзину все хорошо, только не подставляется ссылка на страницу товара. Если же меняю у товара видимость в каталоге на Товары и результаты поиска, то ссылка подставляется. Как можно скрытым товарам присваивать ссылку в корзине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В шаблонах

```
woocommerce/cart/cart.php
woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
```

Найти строку

```
$product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Заменить на

```
$product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```